# Change form target to _blank with primefaces and oncomplete

Tags: javascript, forms, jsf, primefaces

This topis is already present in other posts but none of the solutions mentioned worked for me so here I am, hoping someone can point me in the right direction.

Basically, I have an application with Primefaces 3.5 with 2 commandButtons that execute backing bean methods to generate two different reports as an output stream (no GET available). One of this report is generated as attachment while the other one should be displayed in another tab. Both in the same form.

My problem comes with the report generated in a separate tab: since the reports share the same form, I cannot use target=blank in the form definition and since I have to do validations in my backing bean, I must show possible error messages in the main tab, opening the new one only in case everything goes smoothly.

I tried the following js in the form page:

```
function test() {
    document.getElementById("formRep3_1").target = '_blank';
}
```

called by the bean with

```
RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().execute("test()");
```

after validation successful. But it doesn't work.

I also tried setting an oncomplete="test()" on report button, slightly modifying the js like this:

```
function test() {
    var v = '<h:outputText value="#{repReqStatus.resultCheck}" />';
    if (v.value == "success") {
        document.getElementById("formRep3_1").target = '_blank';
    }
    else {
        alert('no');
    }
    }
```

but it seems the oncomplete doesn't get called at all! Not even if I do another check like

```
oncomplete="if (!args.validationFailed){test()}"
```

So yeah, I'm lost. Any help is really appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you please fix your code formatting?

Comment: Is this AJAX request? You can't open new window/tab with `_blank` if this is AJAX request. You have to manually open new window in `onsuccess`.

Comment: I tried also with onsuccess in my commandButton and with that I am able to open a new tab...but if a validation fails, the new tab gets opened anyway and the error message is displayed in the first page. Is there something I have to set in my code to not trigger the onSuccess in this case? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't change the link's target **during** invoking the link's action. It's too late.

Your best bet is to keep out the `target="_blank"` and instead invoke a JavaScript `window.open()` on the desired URL. You can store the PDF report in session, or prepare request parameters for the URL so that it can generate the desired PDF report based on those request parameters.